# How can I turn of highlighting of empty lines/spaces?

Tags: spacemacs

[http://i.imgur.com/3wZ7XKs.png](https://i.imgur.com/3wZ7XKs.png)

How can I turn off this highlighting of empty lines/spaces?

I am using `spacemacs`, so I would appreciate if answers could tell me how to disable the highlighting through the `spacemacs` infrastructure rather than through vanilla Emacs.

Comment: That is `whitespace-mode`.  I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer because I don't know enough about Spacemacs to tell you how to turn it off.

Comment: The image you linked is no longer available.  Please replace it with an actual image in the post for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to disable whitespace highlight in Spacemacs

#### smartparens

[smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) is an Emacs package for intelligent manipulation of pairs of delimiters such as [], {}, (), <>, "", etc. It is enabled by default in Spacemacs. When you type an open delimiter such as {, it automatically adds a closing delimiter such as }. If you press Enter several times, the delimiters with all space between them including other characters will be highlighted. If you move cursor outside the delimiters, the highlight will disappear. It seems that this is your problem.

I don't use smartparens, so I don't know whether this highlighting is an important feature of smartparens that helps use it, so if somebody can explain why this highlighting may be important as a separate answer, that would be informative.

In any case, if this highlighting really annoys you, you can turn it off buy customizing a specific smartparens variable called `sp-highlight-pair-overlay`. You can either set this variable to `nil` manually, or use [easy customization interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html#Easy-Customization) (read more on how to use it by following the link).

To customize this variable, execute `customize-group`, select smartparens, find an entry that says “Sp Highlight Pair Overlay”, and toggle the variable. Don't forget to save changes when customizing variables using `customize-group` interface! The button to save is on top.

#### whitespace-mode

There is another case of whitespace highlight that might bother you. If you have [`whitespace-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html#index-whitespace_002dmode) turned on, every whitespace character in your text buffer is replaced: space with centered dot, [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_space) with [currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)), newline with dollar sign, tab with left quote mark. They also get different colors too. So it might look something like this:

```
data·Player·=$
»   {·health·::·Int$
»   ,·mana·::·Int$
}
```

If you just want to toggle this mode on/off in the particular buffer, just press <kbd>Space t w</kbd> (`spacemacs/toggle-whitespace`). If you want to toggle this mode globally so that it's always on/off every time you start Emacs, put `(spacemacs/toggle-whitespace-globally-on)` or `(spacemacs/toggle-whitespace-globally-off)` in your `.spacemacs` file.

If you want to read more about different toggles, press <kbd>Space h Space</kbd> and select “Spacemacs documentation”, this is the canonical way to read the docs for Spacemacs. If you want to see which toggles are currently on, press <kbd>Space h t</kbd>.

#### show-trailing-whitespace

There is another highlight for the so called trailing space, when you have extra space characters at the end of the line. In my theme it is highlighted somewhat dark cyan. It has to do with `show-trailing-whitespace` variable that you can also read about in [Section “Useless Whitespace”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Useless-Whitespace.html) of Emacs Manual. Something sets this variable to `t` for most programming buffers and I don't know how to turn it off globally, but I guess it has to do with [this snippet](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/b30c393b8d6cb9c9a57d5cbbaa59e27805f3ebb1/layers/%2Bdistributions/spacemacs-base/packages.el#L432) in `spacemacs-base` layer.

Comment: Where in the config file do you customize `sp-highlight-pair-overlay`? I'm new to spacemacs. There aren't any default variables starting with `sp-`, so I'm not sure where to place this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set:

```
(setq-default spacemacs-show-trailing-whitespace nil)
```

See [this discussion on turning off `whitespace-mode` on the Spacemacs github site](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4419).